# Twitter Bootstrap Scrollspy with Arrow Follow

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

Twitter Bootstrap has scrollspy which lets it automatically add an active class to navigation items based on where you are on a page (anchors). It works great but I was wondering if anyone knows an easy way to get scrollspy to have an arrow graphic under the nav and slide based on the scrollspy active class.

An example would be: https://www.simple.com/ (main navigation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could listen to the **activate** event which the ScrollSpy triggers and then update an arrow div to match the activated element's positioning.  The sliding can be accomplished through CSS transitions.

The main parts of the code would be:

#### HTML

```
<div class="navbar-wrapper">
  <div class="navbar">...</div>
  <div id="menu-arrow" class="top-arrow"></div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.top-arrow {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  border-top-color: #aaa;
  border-width: 10px 10px 0;
  -webkit-transition: left 0.5s ease-in-out;
     -moz-transition: left 0.5s ease-in-out;
       -o-transition: left 0.5s ease-in-out;
          transition: left 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.navbar-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
```

#### JavaScript

```
$('body').on('activate', function (e) {
  var $item = $(e.target);
  $('#menu-arrow').css('left', $item.offset().left + $item.width() / 2 - 10 - $('.navbar-wrapper').offset().left);
});
```

You'll have to do some initial positioning of the `.top-arrow` with CSS, which you can see how in this (not-so-robust) example:

### [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/W5bYZmeHEkxF72emg4f2?p=preview)