# bootstrap component's navigation sidebar + animated section indicator

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I've been trying for weeks to build a navigation sidebar like these images:

[image: Tommy Hilfiger's Left Navigation Sidebar]

[image: Singapore's National Day Parade 2013 Right Navigation Sidebar]

[image: Getbootstrap's Left Navigation Sidebar]

I'm using twitter bootstrap, however, even though their getbootstrap.com/components has a very good looking navigation sidebar, there is no such component in their library and it is so much pain to build one. Therefore, I resorted to using jquery in my attempt to build one like the Tommy Hilfiger's global site.

[Tommy Hilfiger's Global Site](http://global.tommy.com/)

However, I'm new with javascript and css... they are my weakpoints... especially if they are minified :( and I'm stuck at trying to make the arrow marker and have it move along (animating) and always pointing to the current section. I managed to animate the page scrolling though, and my WIP so far is here:

[WIP - Twitter Bootstrap Navigation Sidebar](http://www.jibo-store.com/bootstrap)

Is there any open source components (or preferably bootstrap ones) to achieve that section indicator animation?

I'm so confused with my scripts that are getting messier, so open source component is highly desireble, however, any input on how to achieve it (with script example please) will also be appreciated.. Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Are you asking about the sliding arrow? You'll need to post what you've tried.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Twitter Bootstrap Scrollspy with Arrow Follow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13749282/twitter-bootstrap-scrollspy-with-arrow-follow)

Answer (score 1):

Check out ScrollSpy, the component exist on bootstrap itself:

[bootstrap scrollspy](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#scrollspy)

extracted from:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14366014/474330

So you need to use the scroll spy `activate` event described here: 
http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#scrollspy

Basically you need some code like so:

```
$(function() {
  var $spy = $('.nav.nav-pills');
  $spy.scrollspy({offset: 20});
  $spy.bind("activate", function(e) {
    // do stuff here when a new section is in view
  });
});
```

Here is a working example: 
http://jsfiddle.net/hajpoj/f2z6u/3/

please ignore the fact that it starts at the bottom... not sure if that a unrelated or related bug, but the main point is  you can see how the activate event works